# Remove property from a copied object while retaining property in original object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is my `Employee` object being changed when I've replicated it and I'm making changes to my new variable?

```
const Employee = { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe' }

const EmployeeModifier = Employee;

console.log(EmployeeModifier.firstname);
delete EmployeeModifier.firstname;
console.log(Employee.firstname);
```

Right now this returns

```
> "John"
> undefined
```

Ideally it would return

```
> "John"
> "John"
```

But something is causing the `delete` command to remove from BOTH `Employee` and `EmployeeModifier`. Why? And how can I change this?

Comment: `const x = y` doesn't copy an object. It just copies the _reference_ to the object. So that's why modifications are being observed on both variables.

Comment: `EmployeeModifier` and  `Employee` both have same reference in the memory means that both are same object with different names. You need close an object instead of assigning `const EmployeeModifier ={...Employee}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a reference to the original object.  You will need to do a shallow/deep copy.

This is probably sufficient for you:

```
const oldObject = {
  firstname: 'John',
  address: {
    street: '123 Street',
    city: 'Fake Town'
  }
}

const newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject));
```

This method has it's own problems, though.  You can also use [lodash's cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) which is going to cover more cases.

[Read here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/shallow-copy) for more information on shallow/deep copying.

Comment: This is perfect.